# Get ARN of Lambda role in bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to write a bucket policy denying all access to my bucket except my specific Lambda. I am trying to accomplish this by whitelisting the Lambda's role and assumed role ARN as shown in the policy below.

The reason for this is because I am working under a corporate AWS account where federated users assume either a "power user" or "read only" role. The "power user" role has full access to s3. I do not manage the permissions of these roles, and I need to prevent other corporate users who assume the "power user" role from accessing my bucket.

I am trying to get the role ARN using the AWS:SourceArn global condition context key, but it seems to be that AWS:SourceArn is not working as I expect:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "WhitelistRegistryAPILambdaRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BucketName}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BucketName}/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::{AccountId}:role/{LambdaRoleName}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "WhitelistRegistryAPILambdaAssumedRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BucketName}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BucketName}/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "AWS:SourceARN": "arn:aws:sts::{AccountId}:assumed-role/{LambdaRoleName}/{LambdaFunctionName}"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#AvailableKeys) say that the aws:SourceArn global condition context key is not available for all services. Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: I don't believe `aws:SourceArn` is applicable, here.  This is typically used when an **AWS** resource autonomously performs an action on its own, like a bucket invoking a Lambda function.  A lambda function isn't an AWS resource, in this same sense (Lambda is, your function isn't).  Also, this seems to be something of a continuation of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649044/deny-all-except-specific-lambda-role-in-bucket-policy).

Comment: I see. How can I get the ARN of the role of the Lambda making the request then? Yes, this is related to that question, but I realized my previous question specifically was asking what the role session name of a lambda assumed role was, so I opened this new question asking more broadly about what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it backwards.

Unless you make a bucket public nobody has access to the contents.

Create a role for Lambda giving it permissions to access the bucket. Assign the role to Lambda.

Now only Lambda can access the bucket. If another service or user needs access to the bucket, create an IAM policy or role granting that user or service access.

Comment: Updated my question with the motivation for this approach.