# AWS Bucket Policy to Allow Lambda but block all other external IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to create a AWS Bucket Policy which blocks all external IP addresses, except our office IP, but still allows Lambda functions to access the Bucket.

I know how to make this work using a AWS VPC and NAT, however due to the high costs involved the client doesn't want to activate those.

So far this how my bucket policy looks like, but it's not working:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "GiveSESPermissionToWriteEmail",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files-dev/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "SourceIP",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files-dev/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "81.111.111.111/24"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "GiveLambdaPermisssion",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::6XXXXXX:role/app-backend-dev-lambdaFunctionRole-1XXXX"
            ],
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files-dev/*"
    }
]
```

}

I've think I read all of AWS documentation I could find related to this, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. It might be because their docs, are so confusing and do not cover all the functionality. And I have also searched for solutions here on StackOverflow and other forums but nothing worked.

Comment: Why do you have a need to for a policy that *"blocks all external IP addresses"* when all access to a bucket is disabled by default?  No access to any bucket is allowed unless you allowed it by policy, so it is unclear why you would not remove that inappropriate access grant, rather than try to double down and counteract a grant that should not be in place.  Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: The bucket was publicly accessible when I started the project. And until now that was ok. It hosted some files that needed to be accessed by everyone. Now we are fetching the files through a script hosted on a different server and we need to give that server IP access to the bucket but also lambda as well. Reversing things as you say wouldn't do much, or am I missing something. I would still need to reverse the rules then to give access to the IP rather than denying and then give access to lambda. So basically I would need to do the same thing in reverse, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: I have tried the other way around and it's not ok. If I remove the public access then I can not allow my office IP to access the files in the bucket. I need the access to the bucket to be public, but only allow 1 IP address + lambda functions permission to view the files.

Comment: *"If I remove the public access"* ... What do you mean by that?  If you are talking about the [block public access settings](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) then you may have misinterpreted the purpose of that feature, which explains why you are trying to do this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to whitelist the Lambda function's IP addresses without having them go through a NAT gateway. To do so would require whitelisting every IP address at AWS, which is not only a hugely unmanageable list of IPs, but also entirely insecure since it would whitelist anyone with an AWS account.

The problem is that the `"NotIpAddress"` rule you currently have is always going to apply, so it is always going to deny your Lambda functions. I believe the way to fix this is to add a [NotPrincipal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html) clause to the `SourceIP` rule, so that it doesn't apply to Lambda function calls. Something like the following:

```
    {
        "Sid": "SourceIP",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {"AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::6XXXXXX:role/app-backend-dev-lambdaFunctionRole-1XXXX"
        ]},
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files-dev/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "81.111.111.111/24"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I tried the above, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Also to answer your question, I do not want to whitelist lambda IP's. I want to give Lambda permission to the bucket based on role or arn of the lambda functions or whatever works. But for knowledge I also tried whitelisting the whole Lambda IP range in the eu-west zone the function is running and it didn't work either

Comment: You might try temporarily disabling this rule to make sure this is the one causing Lambda issues. Does the IAM role assigned to the Lambda function give it access to this bucket?

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with the bucket policy for a few days now. If I remove it it works. I have a sandbox lambda function for testing. I've also tried the using NotPrincipal with Service instead of Role, then specify the service as: "lambda.amazonaws.com". When I do this, it ignores my rule completely. (lambda works but also everyone can access the bucket). Shouldn't it ignore it only if the AWS service calling is Lambda? Their docs really do not make sense.

Comment: So very close! The missing part is that the lambda uses an *assumed role*, not the role itself. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649661/21115).

Comment: Thanks @davetapley, that might be it. However I'm no longer working on the project to test it out. Would have loved to nail this back in the day :) That being said, I'm no longer working with AWS and my life got brighter ever since and my hair started to grow back.

Answer (score 0):

This is heavily inspired by Mark B's answer, but fixed to include the [assumed role principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649044/what-is-the-arn-of-an-assumed-role-assumed-by-a-lambda-function).

**Please note that the assumed role is `sts` instead of `iam`**!

```
    {
        "Sid": "SourceIP",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {"AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::6XXXXXX:role/app-backend-dev-lambdaFunctionRole-1XXXX",
            "arn:aws:sts::6XXXXXX:assumed-role/app-backend-dev-lambdaFunctionRole-1XXXX/lambda-name"

        ]},
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files-dev/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "81.111.111.111/24"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```