# AWS Lambda, STS - Assume Role For DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, assume-role

I'm using AWS Lambda(Python) along with DynamoDB.  I would like to have my DynamoDB connection assume a policy for fine grained access.  I'm following [this document as a guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-pooled-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-dynamodb/).

The issue I'm having is that to assume the policy, it uses STS and mentions a RoleArn

```
assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/AccessDynamoWithTenantContext",
    RoleSessionName="tenant-aware-product",
    Policy=tenantPolicy,
)
```

What I don't understand is where this `RoleArn` comes from. I've tried using the role of the lambda, but then I'm met with the error:

```
"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: 
arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/my_lambda_role/my_lambda_role
is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole 
on resource: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my_lambda_role"
```

What role should I be looking for?  And how do I enable my lambda to assume it since I'm not sure you can self-reference a policy in it's JSON.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I do find that this works, but the AWS principal is too permissive from my point of view.  I'm not sure what goes in the principal field

```
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the answer [What is the ARN of an assumed role assumed by a Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649044/what-is-the-arn-of-an-assumed-role-assumed-by-a-lambda-function)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649044/what-is-the-arn-of-an-assumed-role-assumed-by-a-lambda-function

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

The Assumed Role ARN of a Lambda Function is constructed as this:

```
arn:aws:sts::{AccountID}:assumed-role/{RoleName}/{FunctionName}
```

---

#### Details:

So the "role session name" is, in your case, the lambda function name.
You can easily verify this, by trying to call an API from your Lambda (DynamoDB ListTables for example) for which you do not have permissions. The error message in the callback will also contain the assumed role ARN (note that some service such as S3 do not provide detailed error messages when an operation is denied. DynamoDB, Lambda, and most of the recently launched services, will.)

*I'm not sure to understand why you need a NotPrincipal, as probably there is a better way to handle the scenario you described :) More info would be useful to provide a more precise answer.

From the [AWS IAM Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html):*

> Important: Very few scenarios require the use of NotPrincipal, and we
> recommend that you explore other authorization options before you
> decide to use NotPrincipal.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649661/11758843